Unfortunately, cron jobs do not automatically execute this code, but it can be executed manually
Unfortunately, cron jobs do not automatically execute this code, but it can be executed manually.
function listFolderFiles($dir)
{
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($ffs as $ff) {
        if ($ff != '.' && $ff != '..') {
            if (file_exists("$dir/$ff")) {
                unlink("$dir/$ff");
            }
            echo '<li>' . $ff;
            if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $ff)) {
                listFolderFiles($dir . '/' . $ff);
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

$arr = array(
    "Foscam_Rec/C1_00626E813922/record"
);
for ($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++) {
    $mm = $arr[$x];
    listFolderFiles($mm);
}

Please advise whether the problem is with the codes or with the hosting service and if the problem is with the codes, please advise me.

You should probably use an absolute pathname, the working directory of the cron job may not be what you expect.

When the script is executed, it's going to look in the directory that the script is being executed from. So when you do it manually, it's going to look for Foscam_Rec/C1_00626E813922/record in the directory you called the script from. When you execute it from a cronjob, it's most likely going to look from the root directory. Try using a full system path for the directories you're looking for.

You should add error checking. scandir() will return false if the directory doesn't exist.

"Please advise whether the problem is with the codes or with the hosting service". Every programmer has to learn someday that there is no crystal ball that would tell a complete stranger what happened on your server. This is like losing programmers virginity. And realizing that you are on your own. All you can ask is "How can I learn whether it's a problem with the code and if so, which actual problem it is"
